# Trino not able to create table from JSON file

Tags: sql, json, amazon-s3, trino, data-lakehouse

Trino is not able to create a table from JSON in S3.

I use

```sql
create table trino_test.json_test (id VARCHAR) with (external_location = 's3a://trino_test/jsons/', format='JSON');
```

but I get `Query 20230203_154914_00018_d3erw failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bucket is null/empty` even though I really do have file in `trino_test/jsons/file.json`

Different "folder" containing PARQUET works.

Comment: Should not it be `s3:..` not `s3a:...`?

Comment: Then I get `Query 20230203_164757_00019_d3erw failed: Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException No FileSystem for scheme "s3"`